# How to build an efficient and fast `Dockerfile` for a `pytorch` model running on CPU

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I am trying to get an optimally sized docker for running a pytorch model on CPU, creating a single stage works fine. However when I use the below code to create a two stage build, my docker downloads the CUDA/GPU version of pytorch.

```
FROM python:3.11-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app

# Set environment variables.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies & model files
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir torch==2.0.1+cpu --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu && \
    pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /app/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Set environment variables.
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY --from=builder /app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /app/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/* && \
    huggingface-cli login --token xxx && \
    python -c 'from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer; SentenceTransformer("xxx", cache_folder="./app/artefacts")'

# Start the container
CMD python -m uvicorn app.main:app --host $HOST --port $PORT --workers 1
```

EDIT:

So I got this to run without installing CUDA, but the image is bigger than without a two stage 2.5gb vs original 1.5gb, the line changed was:

```
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /app/wheels torch==2.0.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu && \
    pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /app/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

So here I just use a wheel for pytorch too, instead of a normal install as before.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able switch back to a single stage build but reduce the size of your docker container by specifying an external caching directory in your `RUN` command, e.g.

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

The extra files loaded by `pip` for installation will be on your local environment instead of inside the docker container.  Presumably you'll also need to remove `--no-cache-dir` parameter to `pip`.  This should also have the added benefit of speeding up docker builds, since files downloaded by `pip` will remain cached in your local environment.

You must have Docker version >= 23 for this work.